# Can i make WordPress display wp-admin's URLs prettier in browser?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to prettify `wp-admin` URLs, for example, when I go to Pages dashboard, the URL normally:
http://localhost/lb/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

Will be shown
http://localhost/lb/backend/pages
in the browser address bar

Can I achieve this with .htaccess?

I have been playing around with `RewriteRule` but it seems opposite to what I'm looking for
It rewrites URL received from the client when I actually want to rewrite URL before the server send data back to the client.

Comment: Yes that can be done. Most users would use a plugin for that such as a security plugin.

Comment: @MistaPrime I tried thoses plugins that customizes the login url for security purpose, but it only alter the login url, like: http://localhost/lb/login. After loging in, the url becomes http://localhost/lb/wp-admin/some-url again. If you came accross one that does not, please suggest me. Thanks for replying :')

Comment: It's not possible for sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up “pretty URLs” usually requires two things:

- The rewriting of the incoming requests for the “pretty” version to the internal URL,
- and, of course, changing what URLs are output in the HTML code to begin with - because those obviously determine which URL your browser requests, when you click on any links, submit forms etc.

So for that second part, you’d have to modify (probably almost) every URL that gets created in the admin backend. Not sure if WP has any hook for that, not sure how well this would work if maybe the odd 3rd-party plugin doesn’t follow the conventions of how it adds itself to the admin area menu in the first place, etc.

If the URLs that are output can’t be changed, one can still have the server *externally* redirect the incoming “ugly” request to the pretty version first - but that means a bit of overhead, plus with any POST requests you’d have to be really careful, a standard external rewrite would make the browser issue a GET request next, so the POST data is lost …

The one example of URLs you gave is a pretty trivial case still - but in the backend, you’ll have to deal with URLs that include more parameters, stuff like `/wp-admin/post.php?post=1234&action=edit`, certain plugins might send even more for some kind of specific functionality, etc. pp.

---

All things considered, I’d say what you want here, doesn’t make that much sense to begin with. Pretty URLs are also called “vanity URLs” - and that’s what this would be here, more or less pure *vanity* without any real benefits. The potential drawbacks and problems you’ll be likely to run into here, are not worth the effort IMHO.